# How to convert ticks in unsigned long long type to readable time format?

Tags: c, linux, time, linux-kernel, long-integer

I have to write a kernel module for Linux which writes start time of all processes.
I use `struct task_struct` to get information about process.

```
struct task_struct *task = get_current();
struct task_struct *head;
struct list_head *current_list;


struct rtc_time time;
list_for_each(current_list, &task->tasks)
{
    head = list_entry(current_list, struct task_struct, tasks);

    rtc_time64_to_tm(head->se.exec_start, &time);
    printk(KERN_INFO "%d:%d:%d %d/%d/%d", time.tm_hour, time.tm_min, time.tm_sec, 
        time.tm_year, time.tm_mon, time.tm_yday);
}
```

`rtc_time64_to_tm()` takes parameter `long long`, but `head->se.exec_start` has type `unsigned long long`. That's why I can't convert it to readable time format.

```
// Convert seconds since 01-01-1970 00:00:00 to Gregorian date.

void rtc_time64_to_tm(time64_t time, struct rtc_time *tm)
```

Comment: Hmmmm "`rtc_time64_to_tm()` takes parameter `unsigned long`" are you _sure_ this is correct?  I think it takes `time64_t`.

Comment: typedef __signed__ long long __s64;
typedef __s64 time64_t;

so time64_t is long long, but signed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should code truly need to present dates so far in the future, take advantage that the YMD HMS pattern repeats every 400 years.

```
#define SEC_PER400YEAR (60LL*60*24*(365L*400+97))

unsigned long long start = head->se.exec_start;
unsigned long long year = 0;
if (start > LLONG_MAX) {
  year = (start/SEC_PER400YEAR)*400;
  start %= SEC_PER400YEAR;
}
rtc_time64_to_tm((long long) start, &time);

printk(KERN_INFO "%lld/%d/%d", time.tm_year +year, time.tm_mon, time.tm_yday);
```

IMO, a value of `start` that exceeds `LLONG_MAX` is suspect.

Note: `if (start > LLONG_MAX)` not truly needed.

The approach needs a slight mod if TZ, DST is of concern.